# Can I make an instance variable be independent of the prefab variable?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I have a prefab that has a bunch of instances in my level. Each instance has its own attributes that a set in the editor via a script. One of the attributes sets the position of the gameobject. However, whenever I press play, all of the instances default back to (0, 0), which is the default value on the prefab. How do I make the instances keep their position from the editor when I press play instead of going to the prefab value?

EDIT: To clarify: I have an 8x8 grid that I place my objects into. I created a variable, "pos", that stores a Vector2 from (0,0) to (8,8). The "pos" vaiable changes the object's transform position. For example, if I set pos = (0,0), the object will go to (-4,4). The default pos value for all my objects is (0,0). When I drag the object into the game (in the editor), it changes the pos and the transform value. When I enter playmode, the pos reverts back to (0,0), so all of the objects move to (-4,4). The only way for me to prevent this is to manually change each objects pos value so the variable is bolded, and then it won't revert back. Is there a way that I can make it so the pos value never reverts back? (Always seperate from the Prefab pos value)

This is the code that changes the "pos" variable when I drag my object into the scene:

```
private void ChangePosition()
{
    t.position = new Vector2(Mathf.Round(t.position.x * 2) / 2, Mathf.Round(t.position.y * 2) / 2);
    gridPosition.Set(Convert.ToInt32(4.5f + t.position.x), Convert.ToInt32(4.5 - t.position.y));
    tile.pos = gridPosition;
}
```

When I'm in the editor, the pos variable changes correctly, but when I press play, it changes to the pos to (0,0) because that is what the pos is for the prefab.

Comment: when you instantiate something, you tell it where to spawn, it will be offset if the prefab is offset but, it only spawns where you tell it

Comment: So you already have instances in the game, but you also instantiate them? Why? Could you please add more details and code?

Comment: @Eric I fixed my question to make it more understandable

Comment: Some code would also help. I can't see the problem, but I suspect you're not instantiating with the right positions.

Comment: @Eric the default value for a Vector2Int is (0,0), so that's what it goes to.